# strtol not converting string from read(fd,buffer,ssize_t)

Tags: c, strtol

strtol wont convert my string i got from reading a text file.

```
int getNumFiles(int archive){
off_t cur=lseek(archive,20,SEEK_SET);
if(cur==-1){
    printf("lseek ERROR\n");
    exit(-1);
}
bool b=true;
char headerSizeBuffer[4];
char *end;

while(b){
    int numRead=read(archive,headerSizeBuffer,3);
    if(numRead != 3){
        printf("read ERROR\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    headerSizeBuffer[3]='\0';
    printf("headerSizeBuffer=%s  with length=%ld\n",headerSizeBuffer,strlen(headerSizeBuffer));
    long headerSize=strtol(headerSizeBuffer,&end,10);//atol(headerSizeBuffer);
    printf("headerSize=%ld\n",headerSize);

    if (!*end)
        printf("Converted successfully\n");
    else
        printf("Conversion error, non-convertible part: %s\n", end);
    b=false;
}

return 1;
```

}

the console give me this when i run the compiled code

```
headerSizeBuffer=031l_archive  with length=12
headerSize=31
Conversion error, non-convertible part: l_archive
```

all i want to do is convert 031 into a long or int with the value 31.

Comment: You've not shown declarations for every variable, which makes it difficult to be sure.  The `read()` does not guarantee null termination of your string.  OTOH, the report of `strlen()` as 3 suggests that you should be OK and you should not get the odd value in `*end`.  Did your code compile without warnings?  Did you include all headers (`<unistd.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`)?

Comment: the declarations come right before the code i showed you and they are like this
char* headerSizeBuffer;
char *end;

and yes i have all of those header files and got no warnings on the compile

Comment: The problem is you've not allocated space for the headerSizeBuffer!  You're using an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Don't for get to click those "click to update" messages from SO. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odds are that you didn't allocate space, or enough space, for headerSizeBuffer and it is getting overwritten some time between (the start of) the call to printf and (the end of) the call to strtol.

Edit: From the comment above: "char* headerSizeBuffer"

Yup, I was right. Since you haven't allocated any space you have undefined behavior ... which means that any behavior might occur, including what you're seeing. Be sure that you allocate enough space to headerSizeBuffer, either by setting it to point to enough memory (that could be from malloc, or it could be an array, or various other less common means) or, more appropriate to your case because the size needed is known at compile time, declaring it as an array rather than a pointer:

```
char headerSizeBuffer[4];
```

Be sure to set headerSizeBuffer[3] = '\0` to terminate the string before passing it to strtol.

Comment: how would i do that? malloc?

Comment: nevermind char headerSizeBuffer[4]; works. thanks a lot everyone

Comment: @user2014761 You could use malloc if the size of the buffer isn't known at compile time, but since it is in your case, just use an array.

Comment: @user2014761 Happy to help. When you get a satisfactory answer, you should accept it. (You may have to wait a few minutes.)

Comment: now im having new problems. when i changed the declaration to char headerSizeBuffer[4]; my read call now in more junk that from the very start of my file. the output becomes 
headerSizeBuffer=031l_archive  with length=12
headerSize=31
Conversion error, non-convertible part: l_archive

 where the start of my file has "peter_rindal_archive031ls.py 259 1358313654 0000001865..." 
 
somehow the read is getting all messed up.

Comment: @user2014761 Perhaps you forgot to uncomment `//headerSizeBuffer[3]=0;`

Comment: ok thanks i finally got it all working!! just need to add that last line of code. headerSizeBuffer[3] = '\0`

Answer (score 1):

This is because `strtol` requires a null-terminated string, while you are `read()`ing only 3 chars. `strtol` then doesn't see the end of string and keeps reading garbage. You need to set `headerSizeBuffer[3] = 0`.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction too, but...the `printf()` before the `strtol()` determines that `strlen(headerSizeBuffer) == 3`.  It may be coincidence that there's a null at `headerSizeBuffer[3]`, but the information in the output says that it is there, which makes the return from `strtol()` puzzling.

Comment: i added headerSizeBuffer[3] = 0 before the call to strtol but got the same result

Comment: See my answer ... you didn't allocate any space for your buffer.

Comment: @user2014761 you also need to declare headerSizeBuffer as `char headerSizeBuffer[4]`, not `char* headerSizeBuffer`. (`char *` is an unitialised pointer, so you're getting undefined behaviour.)